# Ordering a Foreign Key Field by Date Added

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following two models:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, blank=True, null=True)
```

This creates a database table called `userprofile_userprofile_positions`, with the following three columns:

```
id
userprofile_id
position_id
```

How would I add a fourth field to this table --

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to do this through django, if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new model and specify it in the `through` attribute of your `ManyToMany`.  The Django docs have a section on this exact use case: [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).